# Why do i always have to manually start my Postgres server?

Tags: macos, postgresql

For some reason upon shutdown my Postgres server always stops and upon restart i always have to call;

`pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start`

Can you help me understand what's stopping postgres starting up on its own and what an optimal set up would be? Thanks

**Update:** Mac, Yosemite 10.10.5 is what I'm on. I installed Postgres about a year and a half ago and it used to load on start up just fine. It was a while ago so i don't remember exactly how i installed it, but i'd imagine I did so via cmd line. Something, what exactly I'm unfortunately unaware of, must have happened to my system about 6 months ago as it was around then that it stopped auto-running on start up and that i last looked for 'how to get Postgres up and running manually', i found that start command that i listed above and I've been using it ever since every time i restart. A little late i know, but I've now decided to try to work out what's going wrong. Apologies for vagueness of detail as to what exactly lead to this happening.

Comment: I hope youre on linux. If youre on mac, tell me now

Comment: What operating system and version are you on? And how did you install PostgreSQL? It's not really practical to give a good answer without that crucial information.

Comment: Mac, Yosemite 10.10.5 is what I'm on. I installed Postgres about a year and a half ago and it used to load on start up just fine. Something, what exactly I'm unaware of, must have happened to my system about 6 months ago as it was around then that i last looked for how to get Postgres up and running, i found that start command that i listed above and I've just been using it ever since. A little late i know, but I've now decided to try to work out what's going wrong. Apologies for vagueness of details as to what lead to this happening.